# What's a better way to organise the object's prototype?

Tags: javascript

This is how i attempt to organise the prototypes:

However I have to write an additional "methods" properties to access prototype's function is rather inefficient.

```
var Gallery = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Gallery.prototype.methods = {
    activeCnt: 0,
    inc: function() {
        this.activeCnt++;
    },
    dec: function() {
        this.activeCnt--;
    },
    talk: function() {
        alert(this.activeCnt);
    }
}


var artGallery = new Gallery('art');
var carGallery = new Gallery('car');
artGallery.methods.inc();
artGallery.methods.talk();
carGallery.methods.talk();​
```

Comment: What is the question? What do you want to do?

Comment: Your first sentence seems to suggest that something follows it, but it's not there...? Also, this is not really a code review and suggestion site. I don't think this is a valid question according to the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `methods` property and assign a new object to the `prototype` object of `Gallery`. Also make sure that it has a property called `constructor` which points back to `Gallery`. Here's the code:

```
var Gallery = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Gallery.prototype = {
    activeCnt: 0,
    inc: function() {
        this.activeCnt++;
    },
    dec: function() {
        this.activeCnt--;
    },
    talk: function() {
        alert(this.activeCnt);
    },
    constructor: Gallery
};


var artGallery = new Gallery('art');
var carGallery = new Gallery('car');

artGallery.inc();
artGallery.talk();
carGallery.talk();
```